# Unable to search part of a term with Django Haystack and Elasticsearch

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I have a project based on

```
Django==1.9.2
django-haystack==2.4.1
elasticsearch==2.2.0
```

A very simple search view:

```
def search_view(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q', '')
    sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter(content=query)
    params = {
        'results': sqs,
        'query': query,
    }
    return render_to_response('results.html', params,
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My search index is as simple as:

```
class CategoryIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='name')

    def get_model(self):
        return Category

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return self.get_model().objects.filter(published=True)
```

The `category_text.txt` file is just:

```
{{ object.name }}
```

In my database I have a few items:

- Acqua
- Acquario
- Aceto
- Accento

When I search with my view, I have strange behaviours.

1. Searching with query "ac" I receive no results! I was expecting to have all my items. I have tryed to change the query using `.filter(content__contains=query)` (I know it is the default!) but nothing changed.
2. Searching with query "acqua" I receive 1 result (correct) with the result object, but when I try to print it, the `result.object` field is `None` (the other fields contain the correct information).

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

**UPDATE**

I have found a solution to my problem number 2. Latest Haystack version from PyPi is not Django 1.9.x compatible.
I have just added `-e git+https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack.git#egg=django-haystack` to my requirements.txt file and the issue is fixed. More info about that on GitHub: https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/issues/1291

The other issues is still opened and I cannot find any solution to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may be running into a minimum number of characters issue for #1. Take a look at the [Haystack documents for autocomplete](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/autocomplete.html) which shows an approach using `EdgeNgramField` instead of the typical `CharField`.

Comment: My example was just an exemplification of a more complex case.
I use more than 3 characters usually, and I have tryed to use the EdgeNgramField field.

Comment: It looks like Haystack's default Elasticsearch setup doesn't do stemming out of the box. [Does this link help?](https://wellfire.co/learn/custom-haystack-elasticsearch-backend/) It looks like something similar has been [packaged up to help with these cases.](https://github.com/bennylope/elasticstack)